# Writing length of line along the line

Tags: arcgis-10.1, labeling, linear-referencing, splitting, line

I sometimes have to write out the length along a line for every couple of hundred meters or kilometers. This applies to pipes, when the construction team wants to know where along the pipe they are or talk about.
So far I have done this in a very unefficient way:

- dissolving line segments (if there are multiple along the way, and there usually are)
- split them one piece at the time at specific distances using Editor --> Split
- Convert endpoints to point features
- Generate list of numbers in Excel to paste in a field in the point FC
- label the points without symbol (or with a cross symbol as below)

This works, but there has to be more suitable ways of doing this. I'm not specifically looking for a programmatic/Python solution (even though it is welcome), anything that is a tad less complicated that the outlined workflow will do.. :)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you have not yet investigated **[Linear Referencing](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/What_is_linear_referencing/003900000001000000/)** which would be ideal for that.  Your requirement is one described in brief as one of its **[sample applications](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//003900000005000000)**.

Comment: You're right, I haven't. But I sure will take a closer look, it seems like the very thing I need. Thanks!